# Where is BizTalk 2013? - Azure VM Template

Tags: azure, biztalk

I created a BizTalk 2013 VM on Azure using one of the VM templates from the gallery. Connected to it and BizTalk is not working correctly.

1. BizTalk is not in the Start Menu
2. When I launched the Admin Console, it gave me a Visual Studio 2010 license error. Cannot launch Admin Console.

What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would imagine you have to run the Biztalk configuration Wizard!  I would expect to see the biztalk group in though, so perhaps it's not provisioned correctly ?

Comment: Should I delete the VM and create it again?

Comment: You have nothing to lose I guess?